# jQuery Animation Reverts Unintentionally

Tags: css, jquery-ui

Over the weekend, I've been working on a project that has a nav column and a main column. THe nav column has a toggle button. When the toggle button is pressed, I want to animate the shrinking and expanding of the column. In an effort to do that, I've created a jsfiddle which can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/62eMj/5/). My relevant HTML looks like the following:

```
<div class="ui full-height grid">
  <div class="full-height row">
    <div id="navDiv" class="four wide full-height column" style="background-color:navy;               <a href="#" onclick="toggleNav();" style="color:white;">toggle</a>
    </div>

    <div class="eight wide full-height column">
      [Content Goes Here]
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The relevant JavaScript looks like this:

```
var isOpen = true;
function toggleNav() {
    var options = {};
    if (isOpen === true) {
options = { to: { width: 56 } };
    } else {
        options = { to: { width: 114 } };
    }
    $("#navDiv").effect("size", options, 500);

    isOpen = !isOpen;
}
```

As the example shows, the column performs the shrinking animation. However, the column doesn't stay shrunk. It snaps back to its original size. How do I make the animation change the width of `navDiv` from one size to another and make it stay there?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simplify this a bit by using [.animate()](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) and checking the width of the #navDiv.

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/62eMj/7/)**

```
var w = $('#navDiv').outerWidth();

function toggleNav() {
    if ($('#navDiv').width() > 56) {
        $('#navDiv').animate({
            width: 56
        }, 500);
    } else {
        $('#navDiv').animate({
            width: w
        }, 500);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if there is any real performance gain or if its just a personal preference, but I usually try to avoid using the inline `onclick`.

So the above code could be written as:

**[Working Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/62eMj/8/)**

```
<a href="#" id="toggle" style="color:white;">toggle</a>

var w = $('#navDiv').outerWidth();
function toggleNav() {
    if ($('#navDiv').width() > 56) {
        $('#navDiv').animate({
            width: 56
        }, 500);
    } else {
        $('#navDiv').animate({
            width: w
        }, 500);
    }
}
$('#toggle').click(toggleNav);
```